# How to create release key for android v2 maps in android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, keystore, sha1

I'm trying to use SupportMapFragment in my app, at the beginning it was running ok, but when I switch from the debug to the release It stopped working, the thing is that I've see many pages and many Questions here in stackoverflow but no one could help me, I thing the issue in my app is because I don't use the correct SHA-1.

So I have my key.jks (the one I use to generate signed apk) key store and my debug.keystore, are .jks and .keystore the same? Should I create another .keystore for release? how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
keytool -list -v -keystore <your_key>.jks -alias <alias_for_your_key>
```

will print out the SHA-1

Comment: Thanks for mention .jks extension, i forget to mention it

Answer (score 1):

i think this page can help you: http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/?p=3244

- Should have an older version that does not directly show this data, so at least we should see is the path to test certificate ("Default debug keystore"). As can be seen, in my case the test certificate is in the "C: \ Users \ Salvador \ .android \ debug.keystore" route. Well, if we had to manually get our SHA1 fingerprint we access the path from the Windows command console and run the following commands:

C: > cd C: \ Users \ Salvador \ .android \

C: \ Users \ Salvador \ .android> "C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.7.0_07 \ bin \ keytool.exe" -l

Assuming that your Java installation is in the "C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.7.0_07" route. If not you should only replace it for the right. This should we return multiple certificate data, including SHA1 fingerprint.

For the API KEY that you must put in the manifiest you must put the SHA1 signature obtained previously followed; and the package name of the app

Comment: The debug.keystore will also work for release? I want to publish the app in the google play

Comment: I think so, generates the SHA1 with keytool, then metete in google API's (https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/) and build your project, give permission mapping and obtains a v2 android key with SHA1; package for your project as you put in the manifiest have everything ready, or I think

Comment: @Abdullah explains you it better than me

Answer (score 1):

you just need to run the command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore
```

but replace "mystore.keystore" with your release key path.

Google developers console explains this in a really simple way:

[image]